# Translating "a looming feeling"

Tags: translation

How would one translate "I feel rather relieved today. A nagging feeling still looms over me, but on the surface I feel unstressed." Anything to that effect works.

The first sentence could probably be “今天感觉比较放松。” But what after that? For "loom" perhaps something related to “临头” would work, but that gives the feeling that something is really about to happen, whereas the sentence in English more just signifies something at the back of the mind that won't necessarily manifest itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nagging feeling still looms over me - 一股不安的感覺仍然笼罩着我.

Answer (score 1):

Could try  不祥的预感 which is like foreboding。

I would translate your English thus: (assuming you mean relieved and not relived :))

I feel rather relieved today.
我今天如释重负。

A nagging feeling still looms over me,
我依然感觉烦躁，
but on the surface I feel unstressed.
但是我没有那么紧张。

Answer (score 0):

> I feel rather relived today. A nagging feeling still looms over me, but on the surface I feel unstressed.

Words like "nagging" (incessant reminding [metaphorical]), "looms" (which implies something bad is imminent [and judging from the question, is being used metaphorically]), and "unstressed" (able to relax [metaphorical]) are not so easy translated into Chinese.  Precisely how to translate them depends on the context.  Here's some examples of how I might translate them:

- 今天我有所放心了。我心里还有恐惧的感觉，但在表面上，我没觉得紧张。
- 今天我比较不担心了。虽然我还感到有些威胁，但是我暂时没受压力。
- 我放心了。我虽然还觉得不安，可是现在不焦虑。